# Can I add a feature to be able to create text over underlines?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, documents, forms

I created some documents with underlines (for print outs) but now I am told they want to be able to writer on the underlines. How can I do so without having to redo all of the forms? __________________________________________ like that, am I able to have it so you can add text over lines?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Word Forms.

Below are some pointers to get you started, and you may search for any point which
requires clarification.
There is lots of documentation to be found.

- [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b)
- [Create a printed form in Word](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-printed-form-in-word-f7614383-734b-4fb5-8a8a-dd576969b9bf)